# How to delete an object/structure?

Tags: c, opencv, memory

I'm working on a OpenCV code using C language. My code compiles and runs normally but after some time, a segmentation fault crash and close my application. I think that I'm using too many large structures which end up filling all my allocated memory for the application. How can I erase/delete an object in C in order to free up memory?

Comment: "I think that I'm using many large structures" -- You think? You're not sure? "How can I erase/delete an object in C in order to free up memory?" -- It depends on how you allocated it.

Comment: honestly, you should not use the opencv c-api anymore. they moved over to c++ some years ago ( the reason, being exactly those kind of problems you're faceing now ), and the outdated c-api is only around for maintenance reasons. you should not develop anything new with that

Answer (score 3):

For each `malloc()` or `calloc()` you use you have to use a `free()`. It has to be used exactly once, freeing the same memory block twice is undefined behavior.

Consult [free() documentation](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/free/)

Comment: The OP didn't say anything about using malloc or calloc. Xavier's answer shows a bit more thought.

Comment: @JimBalter I agree with you. The OP provided too little infomation though, and as it is right now, my answer's just as good a guess as Xavier's.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how is allocated. In the case of OpenCV, you should look for `Release*()` functions, to release the kind of object you've previously allocated.